# Upload image into local database using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, localdb

I am trying to upload an image file to database and I keep getting this error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters

I have tried following several tutorials but still the same error occurs.

**Note**: I have also tried looking at similar questions and it didn't work.

So this is the current state of my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Add(ImageFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        viewModel.Categories = _context.Categories.ToList();
        return View("Add", viewModel);
    }

    byte[] data = new byte[viewModel.Img.ContentLength];
    viewModel.Img.InputStream.Read(data, 0, viewModel.Img.ContentLength);

    var image = new Image
        {
            Name = viewModel.Name,
            Img = data,
            Author = viewModel.Author,
            CategoryID = viewModel.Category
        };

    _context.Images.Add(image);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Are you trying to save an image to string column? You would want to store in some kind of blob column, but I'd really recommend not storing images in a database.

Comment: You will increase the size of your db exponentially if you store images in it. Like Blast_dan said store images in a folder and reference the folder in the db.

Comment: I guess that is completely reasonable. So if i store Images in a folder will they be secure as opposed to a database?